# Creating a website with functionalities as given below:

Tags: web, velo

VenEx wants to create an Interactive tool on WIX or any other no code web platform. We would like users to input 6 params on the website, connect the website to an Excel spreadsheet that does the calculation & displays graphs/output back on the website. Pls. Advise

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this in Wix would be to use Velo, which requires a bit of coding. But, you won't need to use the spreadsheet because you can write the calculation logic into the site itself.